# In Java, how does one cast Class references (if possible)?

Tags: java, reflection, casting

Let me setup the problem:

I am working with an API, lots of inheritance going on.  It is very useful to pass around and work with Class type objects (e.g. String.class instead of an instance of String).  It is also useful to range check the Class objects when working with them, so a method might have a parameter like this:

```
public void doSomething(Class<? extends GreatGrandParentClass> typeObject)
{ ... }
```

The problem is that the GreatGrandParentClass has A LOT of children, grandchildren, and great-grandchildren.  So there are times when the type object passed as a parameter, or in a Collection, or whatnot, is a descendant of GreatGrandParentClass, but I'd like to cast the **typeObject** to it's actual type after confirming it's of that type.  E.g.:

```
public void doSomething(Class<? extends GreatGrandParentClass> typeObject)
{
    Class thisType;
    if (FavoriteCousin.class.isAssignableFrom(typeObject))
        thisType = (FavoriteCousin) typeObject;
    ...
}
```

And then I use **thisType** as a parameter to a method that wants a Class object of FavoriteCousin type:

```
public void needsCousin(Class<? extends FavoriteCousin> cousinType)
{ ... }
```

But if I try to cast like I do above, I get:

> ```
> Incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to FavoriteCousin where CAP#1 is a fresh-type variable:
> CAP#1 extends GreatGrandParentClass from capture of ? extends GreatGrandParentClass
> ```

Now, I rather expected that the way I did the cast was not correct, but I'm wondering if there is a correct to do that kind of cast, if possible?

Comment: not sure if i get it right but your cast class object to an actul object so it should be `thisType = (Class<FavoriteCousin>) typeObject;`

Comment: As @justsomeone said, the cast is wrong. Just wanted to add there is method to do that (which actually do the same as a simple cast) : `tthisType = typeObject.asSubclass(FavoriteCousin.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Let's assume you are trying to cast `typeObject` to `Class<FavoriteCousin>`.

What happens is: if class `A` is a subclass of `B` it doesn't make `Class<A>` be a subclass of `Class<B>`. It won't fail at that point because the cast in runtime doesn't care about the generic parameter, but later you will have troubles if you assume the obtained `thisType` is actually a class that whose instances can be assigned to a variable of type `FavoriteCousin`.

What you may want to do is something like this:

```java
public void doSomething(Class<? extends GreatGrandParentClass> typeObject)
{
    Class thisType;
    if (FavoriteCousin.class.isAssignableFrom(typeObject))
        thisType = FavoriteCousin.class;
    ...
}
```

So I wonder why you would want to do the cast on the first place.

Comment: That's effectively what I did, but it seemed clunky, I guess.  So I was making sure there wasn't a better way to do it (a sanity check, if you will).  

I'm still getting used to using Class references and Reflection  so heavily, and I'm doing this alone.  So I truly appreciate you all giving me that sanity check.